# How to pass variable into tag :value as a link to call the data

Tags: vue.js

i'am newbie in vue and i wan't to ask you something, i have tag `:value`, and i wan't to passing variable in that tag so is just like this = `:value=a.anggota_jenis.id` if just like that the code is successful but i want to add variable on it to make the `:value` is more dynamiclly. for example i've variable item.isChild.id and the value for `item.isChild.id` is = `anggota_jenis.id`

why i can't use `:value=a.item.isChild.id` what's the problem??

```
<option
        v-for="(a, index) in value"
        :key="index"
        :value="a.item.isChild.id"
        >{{a.item.isChild.label}}
</option>
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. What value is being set for `value` that is incorrect? Can you confirm that the data you are binding to it is correct?

Comment: The code seems to be ok, PROVIDED that variable value in v-for="" is an array of objects that all have .item.isChild.id properties. Maybe this is the problem? Another remark - id usually is a primitive value and you described as if it was an object that links to another object (value for item.isChild.id is = anggota_jenis.id).